# How can I get the current wordpress timestamp for my mysql injection

Tags: wordpress, timestamp

I need to get the current timestamp for the time that is set within the wordpress settings area? How can I get this timestamp for my mySQL injection?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you elaborate? Alternatively, have you Googled `wordpress get time`? The answer to your question is likely there

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fetch to formatting options themselves, see *[How to get the Date Format and Time Format settings for use in my template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/591/how-to-get-the-date-format-and-time-format-settings-for-use-in-my-template)* at WordPress Answers.

If you wish to get the current time using these option values (which you can get as described in the previous link) you can use the standard PHP `date` function:

```
// Get the timestamp format settings.
$date_format = get_option( "date_format" );
$time_format = get_option( "time_format" );

// Get a date using the timestamp formats.
$current_date = date( $date_format . " " . $time_format );
```

`$current_date` should then hold the script runtime date and time as a string, which is formatted as defined in the WordPress settings.

If you need to adjust the timezone, you need to append one of the [timezone related formatting strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to the `date` function's format parameter.

Comment: Perfect and I figured out that by adding date_i18n instead of just date that wordpress will get the current local time, which is what I wanted. Now the last part of the question, how do I convert that to a timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean a standard format timestamp (as in e.g. a UNIX-timestamp or a certain other construct)? I would look at creating a [PHP date object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) from the date string and using that to output or generate a proper format.